# How can I install the Electrum bitcoin wallet?

Tags: software-installation, python, bitcoin

I would like to install the Electrum Bitcoin Wallet on Ubuntu 12.10.
The Linux instructions are located at http://electrum.org/download.html and say:

> Install **python-qt4** and **pip**:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install python-qt4 python-pip Install electrum:
> sudo pip install http://download.electrum.org/download/Electrum-1.7.3.tar.gz#md5=22a35b0816f7c6c59fbeddb50e832ada
> ```
>
> Run:
>
> ```
> electrum
> ```

It seems the *python interpreter* is already included with Ubuntu.
If I open a terminal and put in

```
sudo pip install http://download.electrum.org/download/Electrum-1.7.3.tar.gz
```

it says

```
sudo: pip: command not found
```

So how do I install python *PIP* or are there any other ways to install *Electrum*?

Thank you.

---

UPDATE: I managed to install Python-Pip from [this link](http://filon.us/slava/?p=189) (using Method # 2. I could not find "easy_install" from Method # 1)...

After that I could install ELECTRUM.
Great so far !!

BUT, I presume that because I'm using the "Try Out" (not the "Install") version of UBUNTU from a DVD-R, then if I reboot the computer I would have to go through the same long-winded procedure again to install Python-Pip and then ELECTRUM.

So, is there any way of adding ELECTRUM (and presumably Python-Pip) to the UBUNTU DVD-R so I can carry the DVD-R anywhere and use any PC to run ELECTRUM?

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu, I am glad things worked out for you. If you have an additional question please start a new Q&A instead of editing your old one with it.

Comment: A request to sync the electrum package from Debian testing has been filed, see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1229843 and add "affects me too" accordingly.

Comment: **DO NOT** use the literal electrum versions pasted in this thread. Make sure you get the latest version of the pip package from https://electrum.org/#download.

Answer (score 9):

You can install the snap from the store:

```
sudo snap install electrum
```

Or search for it in the software center.

Comment: // , This just worked for me.

Comment: That snap is very out of date now: https://snapcraft.io/electrum last updated 2017 appears to be version 2.6.4 (latest today is 4.3.4). Appears to rely on Python 2 and blows up with `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'int'` on Ubuntu 22.10. Best avoided.

Answer (score 7):

I just tried it on 12.10, and it worked.  Try running this:  just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the commands below.

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Then run the steps below in Terminal in the exact order:

1. `sudo apt-get install python-qt4 python-pip`
2. `sudo pip install http://download.electrum.org/download/Electrum-1.7.3.tar.gz#md5=22a35b0816f7c6c59fbeddb50e832ada`
3. `electrum`

[image]
[image]

Once I ran `electrum` from terminal, I got a window that opened, and I clicked on create, and took me through the steps of creating a wallet.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So is there a way of adding ELECTRUM to the UBUNTU DVD-R to use in "Try Out" mode, so I don't have to go through the install procedure every time I use the DVD-R?

Comment: @user3352 If you have a NEW question, please ask it as such by clicking the "Ask Question" button at the top of the page.

Comment: You switched the order of sudo apt-get upgrade and sudo apt-get update.
You should do update first and then upgrade to get the desired effect.

Answer (score 2):

This is working for me in 2017:

```
sudo apt-get install python-qt4 python-pip
sudo pip install https://download.electrum.org/2.7.17/Electrum-2.7.17.tar.gz
```

Also go to the [Electrum Website](https://electrum.org/#home) for more information.

Comment: Could you add import details from this link in case it breaks some time later.

Answer (score 2):

Electrum specifies to only download from their website, and it's easiest to install on Linux with an appimage: https://electrum.org/#download

After downloading use `chmod +x` on the appimage file and then run it as so:

```
nicholas@mordor:~/Downloads$ 
nicholas@mordor:~/Downloads$ ls -alh electrum-4.1.5-x86_64.AppImage 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 nicholas nicholas 54M Dec 27 19:29 electrum-4.1.5-x86_64.AppImage
nicholas@mordor:~/Downloads$ 
nicholas@mordor:~/Downloads$ chmod +x electrum-4.1.5-x86_64.AppImage 
nicholas@mordor:~/Downloads$ 
nicholas@mordor:~/Downloads$ ls -alh electrum-4.1.5-x86_64.AppImage 
-rwxrwxr-x 1 nicholas nicholas 54M Dec 27 19:29 electrum-4.1.5-x86_64.AppImage
nicholas@mordor:~/Downloads$ 
nicholas@mordor:~/Downloads$ ./electrum-4.1.5-x86_64.AppImage 
Warning: Ignoring XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland on Gnome. Use QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland to run on Wayland anyway.
nicholas@mordor:~/Downloads$
```

Answer (score 1):

Add PRO-API repository (http://proapi.ru/deb_repository/) on you system  and install electrum deb package.

Comment: Please specify exact commands, else your answer will not be useful to others.

Answer (score 1):

Commands to install electrum are
(`sudo pip install --upgrade pip` is optional and `-y` forces yes)

```
sudo apt-get install python-qt4 python-pip -y
sudo pip install --upgrade pip -y
sudo pip install https://download.electrum.org/2.8.2/Electrum-2.8.2.tar.gz -y
```