# How to launch Electrum after installing it from an AppImage?

Tags: command-line, software-installation, gui, 21.04, bitcoin

To [install](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/111460/111738) the `electrum` wallet I've [downloaded](https://askubuntu.com/a/1384053/847449) the `appimage` file from the `electrum` website.

After exiting the wallet, how do I then start `electrum` again?

re-running the `appimage` file prompts for re-installing the software:

[image: electrum]

It's already installed:

```
nicholas@mordor:~/Downloads$ 
nicholas@mordor:~/Downloads$ ls -alh electrum-4.1.5-x86_64.AppImage 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 nicholas nicholas 54M Dec 27 19:29 electrum-4.1.5-x86_64.AppImage
nicholas@mordor:~/Downloads$ 
nicholas@mordor:~/Downloads$ chmod +x electrum-4.1.5-x86_64.AppImage 
nicholas@mordor:~/Downloads$ 
nicholas@mordor:~/Downloads$ ls -alh electrum-4.1.5-x86_64.AppImage 
-rwxrwxr-x 1 nicholas nicholas 54M Dec 27 19:29 electrum-4.1.5-x86_64.AppImage
nicholas@mordor:~/Downloads$ 
nicholas@mordor:~/Downloads$ ./electrum-4.1.5-x86_64.AppImage 
Warning: Ignoring XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland on Gnome. Use QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland to run on Wayland anyway.
nicholas@mordor:~/Downloads$ 
nicholas@mordor:~/Downloads$ uname -a
Linux mordor 5.11.0-41-generic #45-Ubuntu SMP Fri Nov 5 11:37:01 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
nicholas@mordor:~/Downloads$ 
nicholas@mordor:~/Downloads$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 21.04
Release:    21.04
Codename:   hirsute
nicholas@mordor:~/Downloads$
```

running `hirsuite` as above.

Comment: Can you provide OS details?  Please [edit] accordingly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install AppImageLauncher in ubuntu 21.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1349951/how-do-i-install-appimagelauncher-in-ubuntu-21-04)

Answer (score 1):

**Maybe the software is already installed after running the AppImage? Try searching for the software in the applications overview and start it from there, or try running `electrum` in a terminal.**

If the above didn't worked then the AppImage they have provided is for testing the software, not downloading it. You can download the software by the following commands:

If you want `snap` **(The snap version of the app is out of date and may break):**

```
sudo snap install electrum
```

If you want to manually compile:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt5 libsecp256k1-0 python3-cryptography
wget https://download.electrum.org/4.1.5/Electrum-4.1.5.tar.gz
wget https://download.electrum.org/4.1.5/Electrum-4.1.5.tar.gz.ThomasV.asc
gpg --verify Electrum-4.1.5.tar.gz.ThomasV.asc Electrum-4.1.5.tar.gz
wget https://download.electrum.org/4.1.5/Electrum-4.1.5.tar.gz.sombernight_releasekey.asc
gpg --verify Electrum-4.1.5.tar.gz.sombernight_releasekey.asc Electrum-4.1.5.tar.gz
sudo apt-get install python3-setuptools python3-pip
python3 -m pip install --user Electrum-4.1.5.tar.gz
```

For more information refer to the [Official download instructions for electrum](https://electrum.org/#download).

Comment: the snap image is woefully out of date, unfortunately.  see:  https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/111460/111738

Comment: @NicholasSaunders Try building from source. Also maybe the application is already instaled, have you checked its installed status?

Comment: on IRC they were saying that you execute the `AppImage` as per any other script, such as `./<script file name>` as a general rul.  I'll have to figure out how to add that "into" the list of apps.  Or even to the dock so I can just click.  But that's a bit of a different question to my mind.

Comment: @NicholasSaunders You can make a `.desktop` file.

Comment: @NicholasSaunders I would recommend compiling from source instead of struggling with AppImage